# Para que serve o método setProperty da classe System no Android?

Tags: java, android

No meu caso utilizei assim:

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
```

Seria a identificação do idioma utilizado?

Answer (score 3):

Quando você executa um programa você "inicia" uma instância da JVM e esta instância possui suas próprias variáveis de ambientes, algumas propriedades sendo inicializadas de forma nativa (método nativo `initProperties`). Na implementação de [`System`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) você percebe que existe uma variável estática de [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), que é o objeto que contém todas as propriedades de sistema e é acessível por qualquer aplicação/biblioteca rodando sobre a instância da `JVM`.

Da documentação de [`System.setProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> Sets the system property indicated by the specified key.

Ou seja, este método cria ou altera o valor de uma propriedade de sistema que são compartilhadas por todas as aplicações/bibliotecas executando sobre a mesma instância da `JVM`.

No seu caso você está redefinindo o *encoding* (codificação) padrão a ser utilizado pelas aplicações/bibliotecas executando na mesma instância que você está executando sua aplicação.

Apenas como curiosidade sobre a codificação na JVM, lá existem três *encodings* "padrão":

- `file.encoding`: [`System.getProperty("file.encoding")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String));
- [`java.nio.charset.Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html): [`Charset.defaultCharset()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset()). Este, na inicialização do *encoding* padrão, usa a propriedade `file.encoding` e caso ela não exista, adota `UTF-8`;
- e o *encoding* de [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html): [`InputStreamReader.getEncoding()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#getEncoding()).